# WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE still required for Android 9 (SDK 28)?

Tags: android

I'm working on a camera app, which is having target SDK 33 i.e Android 13,
on android documentation https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#permissions
it says, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE won't be required, assuming my understanding is correct ?
but when i try to run the app on Android 9 it crashed with error :

```
 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-100-thread-1
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.appcam, PID: 17483
                                                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider
                                                                                                    uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=17483, uid=10147 requires
                                                                                                    android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

am i missing something in understanding the details ?

Comment: are you add this permission in manifest?

Comment: @HanifShaikh yes, following is the snippet of the mainfest
```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>```

Comment: Please Remove android:maxSdkVersion="28" this and try to run